# Subspace Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm studying the book "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces" by Paul Halmos. I'm doing q5 from $\S 12$ Dimension of a Subspace, in chapter $1$.

I'm not all that used to L.A. proofs, so I'm looking for some hints.

Q$5$ Suppose that $\frak L, N, M$ are subspaces of a vector space.

$(a)$ Show that the equation

$\frak L \cap\left ( M + N\right)=\left(L \cap M\right) + \left(L \cap N\right) $

is not necessarily true.

$(b)$ Prove that

$\frak L \cap\left ( M + \left(L \cap N\right)\right)=\left(L \cap M\right) + \left(L \cap N\right) $.

**Attempts:**

For (a) I chose $\Bbb R^2$ as a real vector space an then $\frak L:=\langle(1,1)\rangle$, $\frak M:=\langle (1,0)\rangle$ and $\frak N:=\langle (0,1)\rangle$.

I mean by that the subspace generated by those elements within $\langle \rangle $. I don't know if that's standard use in Linear Algebra though;  Maybe 'spanned by' is the more appropriate terminology.

So $\frak L \subset M+N$ but in neither alone, hence Lhs is $\frak L$ while the rhs is $O$, just the zero vector.

I was wondering are there any other examples that would show this not being true in a different way?

---

For (b) I'm not sure how to approach it.

Like in terms of sets, rhs is clearly a subspace of $\frak L$ and I would guess the following holds:

$\frak A \subset M$ then $\frak A+N \subset M+N$, with $\frak A,M,N$ subspaces of a vector space.

So then rhs $\subset$ lhs.

I'm just wondering the usual way to argue these things in Linear Algebra. Given the chapter name, possibly with dimensions.

Comment: I don't think you can argue with dimensions. Arguing with dimensions would, at best, tell you that two subspaces are isomorphic, it won't tell you anything about them being equal in general. You're on the right track. You should show that RHS is a subset of LHS and vice versa.

Comment: I would like to just add that you can use dimensions in lots of cases, and the way to do it is to show inclusion one way, and then count dimensions.

Comment: @JC574 So do you think it could be worked down using $\frak \dim(M+N)=\dim(M)+\dim(N)-\dim(N \cap M)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint:

If we have a finite dimensional vector space $V$, and subspaces $U$ and $W$ of $V$, then:

$$ (U \subseteq W \ , \ \dim U = \dim W )\ \implies U=W $$

Try and show first that $(L \cap M ) + (L \cap N) \subseteq L \cap( \ M+(L \cap N) \ ) $.

(take an arbitrary element of the RHS and show it's in the LHS)

Then (as you mentioned in the comments), try using the dimension formula to check that the dimensions add up.

EDIT:

although this is good practice of a standard trick (dimension counting) in this case it's actually much easier to do the reverse inclusion the same way as the forward inclusion

Comment: That's be very helpful. I'll keep it in mind for future proofs! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For (b), an element of the left hand side is of the form $m+l$ where $m\in\frak M$, $l\in\frak L\cap\frak N$ and $m+l\in\frak L$, hence $m=((m+l)-l)\in\frak L$ as well. So, $m+l$ is also an element of the right hand side. For the other inclusion, if $a\in\frak L\cap\frak M$ and $b\in\frak L\cap\frak N$ then $a+b$ is both in $\frak L$ and in $\frak M +\frak L\cap \frak N$.

Comment: That's really helpful Thanks. I didn't think to just pick vectors like that! Cheers